# "Boot Error" on live-usb flash drive with 15.10

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, 15.10

I'm trying to install `Ubuntu 15.10 32bits` on a `Samsung NP-N150-JP05FR`, with a live usb created with `usb-creator-gtk` (from ubuntu 15.10, as superuser) on a FAT32 usb flash drive and get this error :

```
SYSLINUX 6.03 EDD 20150813 Copyright (C) 1994-2012 H. Peter Anvin et al
Boot Error
```

Any key pressed make that message repeat.

I often install ubuntu with live usb, using either usb-creator-gtk or UNetbootin. I actually already installed ubuntu (14.04) on that computer a few months ago. I can't figure out the issue.

Already tried :

- different USB  flash drives
- checking .iso integrity
- renaming `isolinux` files to `syslinux`
- checking for `USB Mass Storage Emulation type` option in Bios (no such)
- `UNetbootin` instead of `usb-creator-gtk`
- removing "`ui`" from `syslinux.cfg`

Comment: see also this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1499746)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

According to the release notes at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WilyWerewolf/ReleaseNotes you can't use usb-creator from lower version of Ubuntu ( including 15.04) to make live-usb of Ubuntu 15.10

> Due to changes in syslinux, it is not currently possible to use
>   usb-creator from 14.04 and earlier releases to write USB images for
>   15.04 or later; we believe that it is also not possible to use usb-creator from a 15.04 or later system to write USB images for
>   earlier releases. For now the workaround is to use a matching release
>   of Ubuntu to write the images, but we intend to issue updates soon to
>   work around this incompatibility

You may still make it <strike>from 15.10</strike> or from Windows(universal-usb-installer for example)

I tested `usb-creator-gtk` from ubuntu 15.10 in my virtualbox, it crashed at the end of the process! So we have to say NO to `usb-creator-gtk`! Tested with `unetbootin 608-1` installed through USC, writing to usb succeeded but usb is not bootable!

However, I found away that worked perfectly inside ubuntu, even with older ubuntu version.

1. Right click your `ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso` > **Open with Disk Image writer**
2. Choose your usb drive and click **Start Restoring...** and follow the instruction.

That usb is bootable without any error. After installing ubuntu, you will need to format that usb with `gparted` if you want to store data on that usb again.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful, but I was creating from 15.10.

Comment: @mxdsp try `Disks`, it worked!

Comment: @mxdsp I had the same problem. I tried unetbootin and it didn't work. I tried this solution, from Ubuntu 15.10 and the usb is bootable! :D

Comment: But how can I add persistence?

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky There are many other way to do that but not with `Disks`, I'm afraid.

Comment: If you have a way to do it with persistence, please add an answer. I've tried `Universal USB Installer` on Windows and the trick with downgrading syslinux and using `unetbootin` on Ubuntu. Neither worked (with persistence).

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky Have you tried https://usbubuntu.wordpress.com/make-it-persistent/ yet?

Comment: Help! I opened with disk image writer, restored, then formatted with gparted. Now my usb drive is not recognized at all including gparted.

Comment: Hi @zorkerz , you should open a new question and include all steps that you made to your usb including error messages so that everyone can easily help you.

Comment: There are [two](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1446646)  [bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1499746)  on launchpad which might be related.

Comment: I tried "Open with Disk Image writer" in Ubuntu 15.10, but that program crashes right away. apport sais it is called `gnome-disks` from the package `gnome-disk-utility 3.16.2ubuntu2` (german "Schreiber von Laufwerksabbildern"). I also Tried to open first the program [`disks`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-disk-utility/) and from there i selected the partition and from there I selected "Restore Partition image" which created a stick, but now I get the error on boot "isolinux.bin missing"

Comment: This doesn't see my USB and tells me *Please replace the disc with a supported CD or DVD*

Answer (score 17):

It looks like the good old `dd` command works as well.

Just to be clear:

`dd if=ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=1M`

where `X` is your USB drive identifier. Use `b`, `c`, `d` and not `b1`, so use the drive, not the eventual partition.

At least on my machines, that are Thinkpads T420 and W520, so not super-new it seems to boot using isolinux, so like a CD/DVD.

Some newer machine may have a different BIOS that doesn't allow that. EFI enters then in the discussion, but I'm not an EFI expert so let me close it here.

Verified also with 16.04.

Comment: When to run this command?
I am trying to create usb with Puppy (tahr-6.0.5_PAE.iso) from Lubuntu (Ubuntu 15.10).
`dd if=tahr-6.0.5_PAE.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=1M`
not `/dev/sdc1` ok.

Comment: iso is placed on USB with UNetbootin.

Comment: This is working! Thnx!
**1.** put puppy tahr 6.0.5 iso on usb with unetbootin from lubuntu 15.10, **2.** boot laptop and got "boot error", **3.** on lubuntu terminal with attached usb stick as `/dev/sdc1` run `dd if=/home/w/Downloads/tahr-6.0.5_PAE.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=1M`, **4.** Boot laptop with usb - working!

Comment: Just make sure the USB drive is not mounted. It's ok if you see /dev/sdc1, but this should not be mounted before writing to /dev/sdc. Use `mount` to see mounted devices.

Answer (score 2):

I googled the error and it led me to a page where it mentioned something about a bug in Ubuntu 15.10. I quit trying to create it on my PC then went on to do the following.

Since my only PC with an OS was with Ubuntu 15.10 I had no other choice than to create a live USB from my android device to install Ubuntu on my new PC.

**tl;dr** There is a bug in 15.10. So I created a live USB using DriveDroid and successfully installed Ubuntu on my new PC.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Actually I also tried to create it from 14.04. Same error.

Comment: What about trying DriveDroid?

Comment: I only have android on a virtual machine.

Comment: It helps other users to keep your answers short and to the point. I would suggest you edit it to simply say, "I used DriveDroid on my Android phone." Mention if it let you enable persistence and add a link.

Answer (score 2):

After many hours trying to create a live USB of Ubuntu 15.10 from Ubuntu 15.10, I gave up and used a Windows 10 machine to

1. Format the USB drive
2. Create the live USB with Live USB Creator from http://linuxliveusb.com

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `sudo usb-creator-gtk` ?

Comment: yes of course, I'll make that clear in the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/489683)

Comment: @Zacharee1 This is an attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try Rufus from any windows PC . Set up requires latest syslinux file which Rufus download themselves. I have successfully installed 15.10 with bootable USB created by Rufus after failed attempt with Ubuntu startup disk creator and UnetBootin.

Comment: Actually, I just finished yesterday from a 3 hour online session helping 3 new ubuntu users. They used lili and Rufus. Both did not work. What worked (only for 2 of them) was usb-creator-gtk with sudo and not persistent, it also worked typing live when another "no image found" appeared that offered the grub terminal. Just a heads up that this does not work most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Not actually a fix, but I found a way to achieve a 15.10 installation. I successfully made a 15.04 live-usb (so it's definitely something about 15.10), and I'll make a release upgrade.

Comment: Did this work for you? After upgrading a persistent usb drive, the usb drive refused to boot.

Comment: Yes It worked, but I did **not** use persistent drive. I installed 15.04 on hard drive, then upgraded.