# how do i format my usb stick

Tags: partitioning, usb

i made a live usb using this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696797/boot-error-on-live-usb-flash-drive-with-15-10) to the syslinux error but now i cant format my usb stick for regular tasks using gparted

i tried this other [solution](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/can't-delete-partition-after-using-the-usb-as-a-bootable-usb-for-installing-debian-4175547963/) to format my usb but when i try to make a new partition in fdisk it says "this partition is an extended partition" and that i need a primary partition to create a new partition

please help

if someone could please provide a permanent and easy solution it would be great

im willing to provide extra information (just provide the code to access it)

Comment: In gparted, do: `Device > Create partition table`

Comment: you are awesome
ive been looking for a solution for soo long

Comment: i can definetely do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sometimes happen due to corrupted partition table. To repair it just create a new partition table. This can be done by opening `Gparted` then navigating to `Devices > Create partition table`

Comment: If the answer solved your question then, please [accept the answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/727058/119531) by clicking on [the upvote arrow and then the tick below it](http://i.imgur.com/YN8AQkd.png?1).